# Xpath to click on Eye Icon

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, testing, xpath

In my application, i have to perform click operation on an Eye icon to view the documents but i am unable to generate proper xpath to locate that icon.

Below is the image of HTML code.I am unable to copy paste the code hence attaching the image.

```
    <div title="" class="dragItem row " id="DocSelected-1" draggable="true" type="11" data-content="Salary Slips" data-draggable="item" document-required="1" state="notVerified" accountid="0">
    <span class="col-xs-10 dl-no-padding">
Salary Slips                                    
    </span>
    <i class="document-icon-eye dl-padding-right-10 pull-right" aria-hidden="true" onclick="openValidDoc('DocSelected-1')">
    </i>
    </div>
```

Below is the code tried but i am no such element error.

```
IWebElement salaryeyeicon = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='DocSelected-1']/span/span/i"));
            salaryeyeicon.Click(); 

(OR)

 IWebElement salaryeyeicon = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='DocSelected-1']//span[@class='col-xs-10 dl-no-padding']//i[@class='document-icon-eye dl-padding-right-10 pull-right']"));
     salaryeyeicon.Click();
```

Kindly suggest the right way to locate the element.

Comment: Someone already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first xpath is probably that the `i` element is not nested in any `span` elements.

Maybe it is not necessary to specify the full path to the element, because it's class `document-icon-eye` is more or less sufficient identificator in your concrete scenario. You could use something like this:

```
//div[@id='DocSelected-1']//i[contains(@class, 'document-icon-eye')]
```

I suggest you to use the built in xpath search tool in the browser developer tools. Pasting the candidate xpath in the search field (Ctrl  + F in the Elements view) will quickly show you if the xpath provided will work properly. Probably this could save you a lot of time from successive trial and error compilations and executions of your code.

After the edit the correct versions of your xpaths would be:

```
//div/i

//div[@id='DocSelected-1']//i[@class='document-icon-eye dl-padding-right-10 pull-right']
```